# array_slice incorrectly counts all elements

Tags: php

```
function givemeart($offset) {
    global $db;
    global $arrx; // array
    $end = $offset + 12;
    $arr = array_slice($arrx, $offset, $end);
    echo 'offset - ' . $offset . '<br>';
    echo 'end - ' . $end . '<br>';
    echo 'count - ' . count($arr) . '<br>';
}
```

Result:

```
offset - 24   
end - 36   
count - 36
```

`count` should be `12` shouldn't it?

because from `24 (offset)` to `36 (end)` is `12`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is the length of the slice, not the end point...

> array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL
>   [, bool $preserve_keys = FALSE ]] )

So should be...

```
$arr = array_slice($arrx, $offset, 12);
```

Also as a side note, please try and avoid using `global` and pass in parameters wherever possible.  It makes testing a lot easier and also means that you have a more direct indicator of where your data is being passed around.